# The report definition for report ' ' has not been specified

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am developing web application, in my app i have to print rdlc without preview.my code is following

```
    LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
    report.ReportEmbeddedResource = "TCESS.ESales.CommonLayer.Reports.HandlingBillReport.rdlc";
    report.ReportPath="TCESS.ESales.CommonLayer.Reports.HandlingBillReport.rdlc";

    SettlementOfAccountsDTO objSettlementOfAccountsDTO = ESalesUnityContainer.Container.Resolve<ISettlementOfAccountsService>().GetSettlementOfAccountsByAccId(32);
    if (objSettlementOfAccountsDTO.Account_Id > 0)
    {
        SetReportParametersForBill(objSettlementOfAccountsDTO, AccountReportViewer, report);
    }

    Export(report);
    m_currentPageIndex = 0;
    Print();


private Stream CreateStream(string name, string fileNameExtension, Encoding encoding,
                        string mimeType, bool willSeek)
{
    Stream stream = new FileStream(name + "." + fileNameExtension, FileMode.Create);
    m_streams.Add(stream);
    return stream;
}

private void Export(LocalReport report)
{
    string deviceInfo =
      "<DeviceInfo>" +
      "  <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>" +
      "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
      "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
      "  <MarginTop>0.25in</MarginTop>" +
      "  <MarginLeft>0.25in</MarginLeft>" +
      "  <MarginRight>0.25in</MarginRight>" +
      "  <MarginBottom>0.25in</MarginBottom>" +
      "</DeviceInfo>";
    Warning[] warnings;
    m_streams = new List<Stream>();

    report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream, out warnings);

    foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
        stream.Position = 0;
}

private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
    Metafile pageImage = new Metafile(m_streams[m_currentPageIndex]);

    ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, 0, 0);

    m_currentPageIndex++;
    ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count);
}

private void Print()
{
    const string printerName = "\\\\193.168.0.20\\Printer_Q3";

    if (m_streams == null || m_streams.Count == 0)
        return;

    PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
    printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;
    if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
    {
        string msg = String.Format("Can't find printer \"{0}\".", printerName);
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
        return;
    }

    int i=0;
    foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
    {
        Metafile pageImage = new Metafile(stream);
        pageImage.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"+i.ToString()+".jpg"));
        i++;
    }    
    //printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
    //printDoc.Print();
}
```

i am getting error "The report definition for report ' '  has not been specified"
on line

```
report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream, out warnings);
```

Comment: Please have a look at [I'm getting “The report definition for report 'xxxx.rdlc' has not been specified” in my RDLC report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505700/im-getting-the-report-definition-for-report-xxxx-rdlc-has-not-been-specified/34435136#34435136).

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem while instantiating a report to export and had to set this property like this:

```
wrvReport.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "CommonLayer.Reports.SalesByPrice.rdlc";
```

The difference I see is the `.LocalReport` is the sub-property to set the embedded resource.

Comment: To clarify, **the embedded resource name will be prefixed with the namespace of the assembly it's embedded within**. In my case, for the embedded resource named Report1.rdlc in my Business assembly, I needed `localReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Business.Report1.rdlc";` Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: for **asp.net website check** [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37321117/2218697) answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.localreport.reportembeddedresource%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> An embedded report resource is a report definition that has been
>   stored as a resource in the calling assembly.
>
> If the ReportPath property has been set, the ReportEmbeddedResource
>   property is ignored.

Therefore, setting the EmbeddedResource property is effectively doing nothing and your ReportPath is also failing because it expects a physical file system path.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by setting "Copy to Output Directory = Copy if newer". Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, that means that your code is not finding the rdlc file, you need to either use `report.ReportEmbeddedResource` or `report.ReportPath`. Looking at your code seems to me that you only need to use `report.ReportEmbeddedResource`, the other option is for a rdlc that is located in a specific location in your pc or in a network file system