# I'm getting "The report definition for report 'xxxx.rdlc' has not been specified" in my RDLC report

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created an rdlc report. I have a reportViewer on my form. 
When I try to load the report I get : "The report definition for report 'xxxx.rdlc' has not been specified". I can't figure this out.
I have a datatable with the data I need for the report.
I take this dataTable and I load it back to my database, to a table called "FinalReport". (The reason i'm doing this, is because that rdlc requires some sort of a dataSource.)
I have a table inside my report (table1).
This is my code (inside my form, where the report viewer is located):

```
this.finalDataReportTableAdapter.Fill(this.nehasitDataSet.FinalDataReport);
localReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = @"Resources\VisibleAssets.rdlc";
//I'm not so sure about the following line, but it's the only line that prevented me from getting an error ("no reportdefinition defined"
using (StreamReader rdlcSR = new StreamReader(@"Resources\VisibleAssets.rdlc"))
{
    localReport.LoadReportDefinition(rdlcSR);

    localReport.Refresh();
}

this.reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

I also connected the report to the dataTable and the reportViewer to the report.
I really can't see the problem, and I searched Google for it.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath` property to the path of your report?

Comment: Hi. I don't need to since i have: localReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = @"Resources\VisibleAssets.rdlc";

Answer (score 4):

There are some reasons causing this problem and sometimes the problem might occur only when publishing the same application to `IIS`. If the report file (*.rdlc) is existed in the related location and the problem still continues, you can try the following methods in order to fix it:

> *from* [LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource Property on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.localreport.reportembeddedresource.aspx) 
> *“… An embedded report resource is a report definition that has been stored as a resource in the calling assembly. If the ReportPath property has been set, the ReportEmbeddedResource property is ignored. It also causes the report loaded with LoadReportDefinition to be ignored.”*

*Change:*

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reporting/YourReportName.rdlc");
```

*to:*

```
rw.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "YourFullNamespace.Reporting.YourReportName.rdlc";
```

And then change `Build Action` property to `Embedded Resource` from the properties of `YourReportName.rdlc` file.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error but I'm loading my report in a different way. I followed the instruction on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273267.aspx). Except where they reference `ReportEmbeddedResource` I, instead, used `ReportPath`. When I make that change my report loads.

```
public partial class ReportViewer : Page
{
    private bool _isReportViewerLoaded;

    public ReportViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _reportViewer.Load += _reportViewer_Load;
    }

    void _reportViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_isReportViewerLoaded)
        {
            Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource reportDataSource1 = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();
            BossbergDataset dataset = DataAccessConstants.myDataset;

            dataset.BeginInit();

            reportDataSource1.Name = "DataSet1"; //Name of the report dataset in our .RDLC file
            reportDataSource1.Value = dataset.Table1;
            this._reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
         //My testReport.Rdlc has the [Copy to Output Directory] set to [Copy Always]
            this._reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Reports/TestReport.rdlc";

            dataset.EndInit();

            DataAccessConstants.Table1Adapter.Fill(dataset.Table1);

            _reportViewer.RefreshReport();

            _isReportViewerLoaded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

With my XAML being

```
<Page x:Class="MyProject.Views.ReportViewer"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
       xm![enter image description here][2]lns:rv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;assembly=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    Title="ReportViewer">

    <Grid>
        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <rv:ReportViewer x:Name="_reportViewer"/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Also:

- Make sure you are copying your report files to your output directory. If you are using syntax like `../../Myreport.rdlc` you are probably not copying to the output directory.
  [image: Output Directory requirements]
- Make sure you are referencing the right version of the `ReportViewer` dll. When I went to References > Add Reference... > Assemblies > Extensions and found the report viewer dll it was an old version. I needed to explicitly navigate to

  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\ReportViewer\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll`

  To find the latest. If you get it wrong you'll get an error like

  > The report definition is not valid. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you associate localReport with your reportViewer?  Instead of:

```
  using (StreamReader rdlcSR = new StreamReader(@"Resources\VisibleAssets.rdlc"))
  {
      localReport.LoadReportDefinition(rdlcSR);

      localReport.Refresh();
  }
```

I used:

```
  using (StreamReader rdlcSR = new StreamReader(@"Resources\VisibleAssets.rdlc"))
  {
      reportViewer1.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(rdlcSR);

      reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
  }
```

And it seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like what you said because that rdlc requires some sort of a dataSource :) It is a tricky issue in Report viewer and to solve it I wrote a method that will bind the report direct from Datatable:

```
private void GenerateReportDirect(ReportViewer reportViewer, string datasource, DataTable dt, string reportpath)
{
    reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportpath;
    ReportDataSource repds = new ReportDataSource(datasource, dt);
    reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(repds);
    reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
}
```

and to implement this method you have to specify putting the string of dataset table adapter just a name but our report will take the data to bind from the data table (we will cheat on our report viewer :) )

```
private void BindReport(DataTable dt)
    {
            string reportPath = Server.MapPath("StudentBus.rdlc");
            GenerateReportDirect(ReportViewer1, "StudentDataSet_usp_RPT_StudentBus", dt, reportPath);
    }
```

I hope this will help :) .

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue occur with one of my reports.  It was a local, embedded report.

1. I didn't have the `ReportEmbeddedResource` property set.
2. When I did set `ReportEmbeddedResource property`, it still gave the error because the report name had incorrect case - `myApp.reports.rptMyJobstatus.rdlc` instead of `myApp.reports.rptMyJobStatus.rdlc`.

Therefore, you need to check both of these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Changing Build Action property to Embedded Resource from the properties of XYZ.rdlc file will help you fix the problem for most part if you are setting ReportEmbeddedResource property in the code and not report path.