# The source of the report definition has not been specified

Tags: c#

I'm using following Codes typing the parameters.....

```
var invdata = SaleInvCode.GetbyId(invID);
var invdat = (from a in db.invDetails where a.InvDetailID == invID select new { a.SaleInv, a.ProName, a.Discription, a.SaleQTY, a.SalePrice, a.SaleAmount }).ToList();
//var invdetai = from a in db.invHeaders select a;
/////////////////////////
invHeader.DataSource = invdata;
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(reportViewer1.LocalReport.GetDataSourceNames()[0], invHeader));
reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
```

**error**

```
Error:: The source of the report definition has not been specified
```

I'm creating Report parameter.....

Comment: Please have a look at [I'm getting “The report definition for report 'xxxx.rdlc' has not been specified” in my RDLC report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505700/im-getting-the-report-definition-for-report-xxxx-rdlc-has-not-been-specified/34435136#34435136).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the report viewer which local report to use before you can assign any parameters.