# The source of the report definition has not been specified 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, reportviewer

I'm working with Asp.net MVC 4.

I have this snippet:

```
var data = // fill my data.
var rds = new ReportDataSource("MyDataset", data);

var viewer = new ReportViewer();

viewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Reports/Report1.rdlc";

string mimeType, encoding, extension;
string[] streamids;
Warning[] warnings;

var buffer = viewer.ServerReport.Render("PDF", "C:", out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
```

But the method `Render` throw a exception:

> **Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.MissingReportSourceException**: The source of the report definition has not been specified.

I'm search and found: [this 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903170/the-source-of-the-report-definition-has-not-been-specified), [this 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471661/the-source-of-the-report-definition-has-not-been-specified), [this 3](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/44af0ba6-498b-48a1-92a0-f0e3f842e795/the-source-of-the-report-definition-has-not-been-specified?forum=reportingservicespt) and others.

Using these links I tried:

Try 1:

```
viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"../Reports/Report1.rdlc";
```

Try 2:

```
viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"../../Reports/Report1.rdlc";
```

Try 3:

```
viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"~/Reports/Report1.rdlc";
```

Try 4:

```
viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/Reports/Report1.rdlc");
```

Try 5:

```
var fileName = Server.MapPath(@"~/Reports/Report1.rdlc");
using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    viewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(fs);
}
```

However all these attempts throw the same exception.

Anyone has some idea? I'm several hours trying to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that you have either used one of the following when using

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"path/reportName.rdlc"
```

scenario when report is located other than bin folder of debug or release

or you can use

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"reportName.rdlc"
```

when its at application.StartupPath

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = // fill my data.
var rds = new ReportDataSource("MyDataset", data);

var viewer = new ReportViewer();

viewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);




            string fileName=  "Reports/Report1.rdlc";

        FileStream S = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(fileName), FileMode.Open);
        viewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(S);
        S.Close();

string mimeType, encoding, extension;
string[] streamids;
Warning[] warnings;

var buffer = viewer.ServerReport.Render("PDF", "C:", out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
```

Comment: Thanks for trying help, but this is the same snippet used in question (try 5).

Comment: Only difference with your try 5 is that I don't have ~ character in front my code. This code is working on my side. I don't know what else is wrong.