# The report definition for report 'Report1' has not been specified

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reportviewer, rdlc

I created a rdlc report in visual studio 2012 webapplication project.t Did all steps correctly (all are done from the UI's) not do any coding when I run the project I alwasy get following error

```
An error occurred during local report processing.
    The report definition for report 'Report1' has not been specified
        Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

then set the   ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath= property from the codebehind.then error desapier and working properly.my headache was how to set this property without doing any coding ?

Comment: Please have a look at [I'm getting “The report definition for report 'xxxx.rdlc' has not been specified” in my RDLC report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505700/im-getting-the-report-definition-for-report-xxxx-rdlc-has-not-been-specified/34435136#34435136).

Answer (score 9):

replace this line in your report view

```
<LocalReport ReportEmbeddedResource="report.Report1.rdlc">
```

to this line

```
 <LocalReport Reportpath="Report1.rdlc">
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me

Answer (score 6):

If by 'without doing any coding' you mean without using the code-behind file, then you can set the `ReportPath` property inside the `ReportViewer` control itself like so:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer id="report" runat="server">
    <LocalReport ReportPath="Your report path here"></LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Comment: hi Sara,yes i mean code behind,when we select report from the reportviewer controller why is that not set the local report parth ?

Comment: @AruniGodage A `ReportViewer` control _needs_ a `ReportPath`. What do you mean by 'why is that not set the local report parth'?

Comment: for **asp.net website check** [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37321117/2218697) answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

The report file haven't been copied to the solution's target output directory, so in the report property, change the "Build Action" to "Content" and "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always"

Comment: It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and the problem was with NULL values from SQL.
Check if you have null values in your SQL result. I  lost two days searching what is not ok with "The report definition for report '' has not been specified".