# RDLC Local Report after deploy not working

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment, rdlc, localreport

I build a Windows Application with Local Report using RDLC , it works well when i run the code inside VS2012 , but when i deploy it the application gives me some errors:

> An error ocured during local report processing.
>
> The report definition for report "Report1.rdlc" has been not specified
>
> Could not find a part of the path "C:...\Report1.rdlc".

Code im using:

```
DataSet2 ds = new DataSet2();
                DataTable dt = ds.Table2;

                DataRow dr = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    dr = ds.Table2.NewRow();
                    dr["Nr"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    dr["Ary"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    dr["Car"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    dr["Total"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                    dr["Total2"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                    // MessageBox.Show(dr["Vetura"].ToString());
                    ds.Table2.Rows.Add(dr);
                    dt.AcceptChanges();
                }

                dr.AcceptChanges();

               

                string exeFolder = (Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath)).Substring(0, (Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath)).Length - 3);
                string reportPath = Path.Combine(exeFolder, @"Report1.rdlc");
                //MessageBox.Show(reportPath.ToString());
                Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource rds = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet2", ds.Tables[0]);
                ra.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                ra.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
                ra.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath;
                if (textBox2.TextLength > 0)
                {
                    ReportParameter Percentage = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("Percentage", "-" + textBox2.Text + "%");
                    ReportParameter Total = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("Total", textBox3.Text);
                    ra.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { Percentage });
                    ra.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { Total });
                }
                //HERE IS THE FIRST ERROR , WHEN I PASS THE THE TEXT TO THE PARAMETER
                ReportParameter Klienti = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("Klienti", textBox1.Text);
                ra.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { Klienti });
                ra.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: Can you try setting the working directory to exefolder and see if that helps? Just open command prompt, change directory to exe folder and run the exe

Comment: @GaneshR. i didnt quite understand you , what do you mean setting the working directory to exefolder ?

Comment: Suppose your exe is in C:\Data, open command prompt and type cd /d C:\Data. Then just type the exe name and press enter. Basically your applications working directory was set to c:\Data

Comment: Ok , i just tryed that ,nothing wrong there , it opens the application but when i pres the button to render the ReportViewer it fails

Comment: Does the report.rdlc have an embedded rdlc file?

Comment: When i deploy and install it , in the install directory it doesnt give me a report.rdlc file , i put the BUILD ACCTION to Embedded Resource , but still no luck

Comment: Manually copy the report1.rdlc file to the output directory. It needs to be physically present.

Comment: I tryed that too , didnt work.
This looks really hard to fix :X

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvar/archive/2014/01/20/report-definition-not-specified-error-with-rdlc-report.aspx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650571/the-report-definition-for-report-report1-has-not-been-specified Both of them are asking you to set the ReportPath and need the Report1.rdlc in the exe folder

Comment: @GaneshR. thank you so much friend, u helped me solve this problem :)
i posted another answer there so people having this problem can see it better :) Best Regards

Comment: Please have a look at [I'm getting “The report definition for report 'xxxx.rdlc' has not been specified” in my RDLC report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505700/im-getting-the-report-definition-for-report-xxxx-rdlc-has-not-been-specified/34435136#34435136).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ganesh R.I managed to fix the issue .
I was giving the ReportPath manually by code, so i gave it automaticly by selecting the path on the ReportViewer , it did the job.