# 'the report definition for report '<vsprojectname>.report1.rdlc' has not been specified' error in VS2013 WPF/C# application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, reportviewer, windowsformshost

I want to have reporting feature in my application (Visual Studio 2013, WPF, C#). I needed to start with something simple and found this Microsoft walk-through : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273267.aspx.

I believe I followed all the instructions, but in vain - the only result is the following message in the main window:

> an error occured during local report processing. the report definition
>   for report '.report1.rdlc' has not been specified

Could you please consult me?

Thank you in advance!

av

Comment: Please have a look at [I'm getting “The report definition for report 'xxxx.rdlc' has not been specified” in my RDLC report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505700/im-getting-the-report-definition-for-report-xxxx-rdlc-has-not-been-specified/34435136#34435136).

Answer (score 0):

please find an update !

the reason of the error is in this code line :

```
this._reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "<VSProjectName>.Report1.rdlc";
```

this `"<VSProjectName>.Report1.rdlc"` does not 'point' to a correct report. i believed `<VSProjectName>` would return the name of the project. ( how ? it is just a string ! ... )

i fixed the bug but got a more sophisticated one !

will keep you updated.

av

Comment: be sure your 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms' assembly is of the correct version. it should be 11.0.0.0 for visual studio 2013. please find details here : [link](https://cmatskas.com/resolving-rdlc-error-the-report-definition-is-not-valid-in-visual-studio-2012/) ! av