# "The report definition for report 'xxx' has not been specified."

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, reporting-services, webforms

I'm trying out SSRS for the first time with an ASP.Net web form.

I created a local RDLC report and used a ReportViewer in the "Default" web form. Under the smart tag I chose "Choose Report" and selected the RDLC report.

When I pressed f5 to run the report the following error was displayed even though I did choose the report from the smart tag.

```
"The report definition for report 'xxx' has not been specified."
```

Please let me know why this is not working as expected.

Thanks.

Coding for the report:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">
<section class="featured">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <hgroup class="title">
            <h1><%: Title %>.</h1>
            <h2>Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET application.</h2>
        </hgroup>
        <p>
            To learn more about ASP.NET, visit <a href="http://asp.net" title="ASP.NET Website">http://asp.net</a>.
            The page features <mark>videos, tutorials, and samples</mark> to help you get the most from ASP.NET.
            If you have any questions about ASP.NET visit <a href="http://forums.asp.net/18.aspx" title="ASP.NET Forum">our forums</a>.
        </p>
    </div>
</section>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="739px">
    <LocalReport ReportEmbeddedResource="WebApplicationFirstReports.Web Products.rdlc">
        <DataSources>
            <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="DataSet1" />
        </DataSources>
    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="DataSetWebTableAdapters.DataTable1TableAdapter"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Could you share your code? I know that the ReportViewer is very stubborn if placed "wrong."

Comment: Yes. I will include it as part of the question.

Comment: Did the answer below answer your question?

Comment: Thanks. Adding the ReportPath in made it find the report. I'm not sure why it did not add it in from the designer.

Comment: Had the same exact issue. I went nuts and decided to start to type letters to see what would pop up and ReportPath did. So I tried it and it worked. Only a few hours wasted.

Comment: Please have a look at [I'm getting “The report definition for report 'xxxx.rdlc' has not been specified” in my RDLC report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505700/im-getting-the-report-definition-for-report-xxxx-rdlc-has-not-been-specified/34435136#34435136).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, so it looks like you are missing your ReportPath in your local report. Here is a code example straight from my working project.

```
<body class="center">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCheckDate" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Height="800px" Width="620px" CssClass="center" BackColor="White" ShowBackButton="False" ShowPageNavigationControls="False">
                <LocalReport ReportPath="Paystub.rdlc" ReportEmbeddedResource="PayrollApplication.Paystub.rdlc">
                    <DataSources>
                        <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="SqlDataSource1" Name="DataSet1" />
                    </DataSources>
                </LocalReport>
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:pay %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ViewPaychecks] WHERE ([CHKDATE] = @CHKDATE)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblCheckDate" Name="CHKDATE" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Let me know if this helped! I used an SqlDataSource but this should work with the ObjectDataSource as well.

Answer (score 5):

This happens when you deploy in live site and report's `.rdlc` file is not yet published in the site, so **here is the solution** which worked form me:

1. Right click on your Report's '.rdlc' file  , select properties then set the property **Build Action** of the rdlc to **Content**.

**Screen Shot:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[This](http://www.jefclaes.be/2009/05/report-definition-for-report-path-has.html) and [This](http://asadkhan1973.blogspot.com/2011/06/report-definition-for-report-path-has.html)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a the same error message and resolved it by adding the following two (2) lines at the end of the report definition:

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Answer (score 0):

copy all the report and paste it on your published folder