# The Report Definition for report has not been specified

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, stored-procedures, rdlc

**Hy Everyone!** Hope you are doing well, I am doing my final year project but I am stuck with its last phase i.e reporting. I tried to use the RDLC report using [this](https://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2204/rdlc-reporting-in-windows-application) tutorial.

But When I run it gives me this Error;

```
An Error Occured during local error processing
The report definition for report "report1" has not been specified
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Here is My sample report (simple form where I use the report viewer) code;

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StockRegisterManagementSystem.Views
{
    public partial class SampleReportForm : Form
    {
        public SampleReportForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SampleReportForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'sampleDataSet1.item_procedure' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.item_procedureTableAdapter.Fill(this.sampleDataSet.item_procedure);
           
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport(); 
        }

    }
}
```

I have seen the following answers already available on **StackOverflow**

[The report definition for report ' ' has not been specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470280/the-report-definition-for-report-has-not-been-specified)

You know how it is painfull when you are on last phase but can't move on .

**Thanks In Advance ;)**

Comment: Check the answer at the below site near the bottom.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5b6cd9bf-baf0-4726-8507-5e732c48dd10/the-report-definition-for-report-xxx-has-not-been-specified?forum=vsreportcontrols

Comment: that answer not working in my case, Or may be i am not urderstanding that problem in a depth.

Answer (score 0):

I tested according to the documentation you used and did not reproduce your problem. You could try to check my following steps to see if they are consistent with yours.

1. Create a Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) project named RDLC in Visual Studio 2019.
2. Create Report.rdlc:
   Right-click the project name -> select Add -> click New Item... -> search and select Report -> named Report1.rdlc -> click Add.
3. Create DataSet.xsd:
   Right-click the project name -> select Add -> click New Item... -> search and select DataSet -> named DataSet1.xsd -> click Add.
4. Add data to DataSet.xsd(I am using the existing data in SQL Server Object Explorer):
   Click View->Select SQL Server Object Explorer->Copy the server name of the standby database .

[image]

Right Click on the Empty Region -> Select Add New Table Adapter -> Click New Connection…-> Paste the server name into Server name-> Select the database name to be used.

[image]

Click Next to the Enter a SQL Statement page-> Click Query Builder...-> Select the data table you want to use -> click Add and then click Close.
[image]

Check * (All Columns) -> click Add

[image]

5. Add data to Rerport1.rdlc[Design]:
   Open Report.rdlc[Design]->right-click and select Insert->click Matrix->add data to Matrix .

[image]

6. Add Nuget package to use ReportViewer:
   Right-click the project name -> select Manage Nuget Packages... -> click Browse -> enter and search for the download package **Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms**.
7. Under Form1.cs[Design] page -> search and add ReportViewer in Toolbox.

[image]

8. The code of Form1.cs:

   using System;
   using System.Windows.Forms;
   namespace rdlc
   {
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
   public Form1()
   {
   InitializeComponent();
   }
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   this.AddressTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.Address);
   this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
   }
   }
   }
9. The result is shown in the figure.

[image]